# no such file or directory package.json

Tags: docker

I am working with a mounted volume on my host
When I run `docker-compose build && docker-compose up -d` I get:

```
[4/5] RUN npm install:
#7 4.268 npm ERR! code ENOENT
#7 4.268 npm ERR! syscall open
#7 4.268 npm ERR! path /var/www/html/package.json
#7 4.269 npm ERR! errno -2
#7 4.271 npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/www/html/package.json'
#7 4.271 npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.    

executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm install]: exit code: 254
ERROR: Service 'node' failed to build : Build failed
```

This is the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
node:
    build:
        context: ./nodejs-project
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: node
    volumes:
        - ./nodejs-project:/var/www/html
```

And this is the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:alpine

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html

WORKDIR /var/www/html

EXPOSE 3000

RUN npm run build

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

I believe it has something to do with the fact that I both mount the volume from the `docker-compose.yml` and making a `WORKDIR` from the `Dockerfile` and it somehow overrides it. But I can't find a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A volume mount is present at container run time.

the [`RUN`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) command is executed at image build time.

If the image is built, the mount is not present. Hence, the directory `/var/www/html` is empty.

If we want to have the files present at container build time, we should [`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) the files in the `dockerfile`.

Alternatively, we can run `npm run build` when the container is started (through [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)) instead of image build time.

Comment: thank you. now it's more clear! (I'm just starting with Docker)